# Which holomorphic curves can be leaves of a non-singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb C^2$?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, foliations

It is easy to see that for any entire function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, its graph $G(f) = \{(z,f(z)) \in \mathbb C^2 \mid z \in \mathbb C\}$ can be translated by $(0,c)$ for any $c \in \mathbb C$, so that all the translated graphs $\{G(f) + (0,c) \mid c \in \mathbb C\}$ form the leaves of a holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb C^2$.

If $V : \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$ defines a holomorphic and nowhere zero vector field on $\mathbb C^2$, then there is a unique non-singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb C^2$ by holomorphic curves that are everywhere tangent to $V$. These are the orbits of the local $\mathbb C$-action that $V$ induces on $\mathbb C^2$. It is known that the leaves of such a foliation must be topologically either planes or cylinders.

Is it known exactly which holomorphic curves $X \subset \mathbb C^2$ can be a leaf of a non-singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: How do you know that $V$ induces an action of the additive group $\mathbb C$? Don't you just get a (holomorphic) local flow in general, rather than a flow?

Comment: Good point; it may not be all of ℂ, just a local ℂ-action. (Though there is always a holomorphic foliation induced.) I will modify the question.

Comment: It was pointed out to me, I think by @TheAmplitwist, that using Unicode like ℂ instead of TeX like $\mathbb C$ makes questions unsearchable—I guess the search engine only sees ASCII.  So I think that it is friendlier to use TeX at the very least in the body.

Comment: I would if I knew how, but I don't.

Comment: Ignorant question: is it true that every holomorphic line-bundle on $\mathbb C^2$ is trivial? If so, then it is true (as one might imagine you are thinking) that every foliation is spanned by some (nowhere vanishing) vector field. Also, if so, then every foliation is determined by a nowhere vanishing $1$-form.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie for your first question yes, this is just the statement that the Picard group of $\mathbb C^2$ vanishes; see e.g. the fourth example on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group

Comment: @Kevin Casto: But this is holomorphic, not algebraic. Is the answer the same?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Sure yeah, that example is about the holomorphic case -- the exponential exact sequence only applies in the holomorphic setting, not algebraic (since it uses the exponential map!) Apparently even Quillen-Suslin is just a calculation in the holomorphic setting.

Comment: Thanks, @C7X!..